# vpnc through openvpn failed

Tags: openvpn, cisco-vpn, vpn

I should connect to a Cisco VPN server for example 95.94.66.6, it configured to accepts  specified IPs so I launched a server with a registered IP on Cisco which runs an `openvpn` server. The scenario is like this: I connect to my vpn server then connect to Cisco with `vpnc-connect` command on client. All thing to here are OK. The problem is that when I connect to vpn server all internet traffics goes out through it. To avoid it I changed `server.conf` on vpn server and disabled `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` and added `push "route 95.94.66.6 255.255.255.255 vpn_gateway 1"` then restarted the `openvpn` server. After connecting on client, routes are ok, also there is no `0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.1/1` as expected. I have the ping of the 95.94.66.6 and correctly `traceroute`. But `vpnc-connect` failed and says `no response from target`. I rolled back the configuration and this time vpnc could connect. Also I checked the routes and iptables on vpn server and client and there is no difference while using two different config.

Why? and How to fix it?

```
/-----\        /-----------------\        /------\
|Cisco|<------>|My Own VPN Server|<------>|Client|
\-----/        \-----------------/        \------/
```